# Pacmd - Configure profile for a headset

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth

When I configure my headset to a particular profile (I prefer using High Fidelity Playback over Headset Unit) for my [Bose QC35 Bluetooth headset](https://www.bose.com/content/consumer_electronics/b2c/north_america/websites/en_us/product/qc35_ii_bose.html#ProductTabs_tab4), [pavucontrol](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pulseaudio) does not let me configure it to that profile. Even if the pavucontrol GUI shows that I have changed it to High Fidelity Playback, reopening the pavucontrol GUI shows that it is back at Headset Unit.

This is only for my Bluetooth headset. Changing the configuration for *analog stereo* via pavucontrol works.

I can see the profiles list for my headset using `pacmd ls` -

```
index: 2
    name: <bluez_card.4C_87_5D_0A_F4_C8>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    owner module: 27
    properties:
        device.description = "Reik's Bose"
        device.string = "4C:87:5D:0A:F4:C8"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headphone"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_4C_87_5D_0A_F4_C8"
        bluez.class = "0x240418"
        bluez.alias = "Reik's Bose"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headphones-bluetooth"
    profiles:
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: yes)
        a2dp_sink_sbc: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink: SBC) (priority 40, available: unknown)
        a2dp_sink_aac: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink: AAC) (priority 40, available: unknown)
        a2dp_sink_aptx: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink: aptX) (priority 40, available: no)
        a2dp_sink_aptx_hd: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink: aptX HD) (priority 40, available: no)
        a2dp_sink_ldac: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink: LDAC) (priority 40, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
    active profile: <headset_head_unit>
    sinks:
        bluez_sink.4C_87_5D_0A_F4_C8.headset_head_unit/#2: Reik's Bose
    sources:
        bluez_sink.4C_87_5D_0A_F4_C8.headset_head_unit.monitor/#2: Monitor of Reik's Bose
        bluez_source.4C_87_5D_0A_F4_C8.headset_head_unit/#3: Reik's Bose
    ports:
        headphone-output: Headphone (priority 0, latency offset 50000 usec, available: yes)
            properties:

        headphone-input: Bluetooth Input (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
```

I was able to manually switch profiles till a few days ago, but now the profiles' availability seem to be unknown -

```
[reik@reik-msi ~]$ pacmd set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink_sbc
Failed to set card profile to 'a2dp_sink_sbc'.
```

and

```
[reik@reik-msi ~]$ pacmd set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink_aac
Failed to set card profile to 'a2dp_sink_aac'.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try resetting the bluetooth connection settings by removing the appropriate entry from `/var/lib/bluetooth/`